# VSCode extension: Highlighting semantic tokens using TextMate grammar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, syntax-highlighting

I want my language server to highlight json using semantic tokens and could do that by letting the server parse the json. However, I think it would be a better to let the server send a semantic token containing the json to the client and then let the client apply standard highlighting in the region of that token, but I don't know if and how that is possible.

I have tried to map the semantic token to the `source.json` scope, but that didn't highlight it at all. It seems to be that the scope mapping only works when mapping to scopes which are directly colored (for example, I can map it to `string.quoted.double.json`), but no more grammar is applied after the mapping. This makes sense though, because I think multiple grammars could use the same scopes.